# How to fix a segmentation fault run time error

Tags: c++

I have a trouble dealing with the class Pila which is an ADT using a linked list of Records, more precisely the problem is in the push method of the class Pila. When T type (the elem attribute type of the record ) is a int there is no problem and the return value is 0 as it should be but when T type is PaccoPostale the return value is 3221225477 but it seems to do its job anyway.
Can anyone help me figure out what is happening and/or understand to change this strange behaviour ?!?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define N 20
using namespace std;


class PaccoPostale{
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ,const PaccoPostale& );
        friend istream& operator>>(istream& ,PaccoPostale& );
        public:
            explicit PaccoPostale(const int& c=0,const float& p=0, const char* i=""):codice(c),peso(p),indirizzo(new char[strlen(i)+1]){
                strcpy(indirizzo,i);
            }



PaccoPostale(const PaccoPostale& p)
            :codice(p.codice),peso(p.peso),indirizzo(new char[strlen(p.indirizzo)+1]){
                strcpy(indirizzo,p.indirizzo);
            }

            ~PaccoPostale(){delete [] indirizzo;}
            int get_codice()const{return codice;}
            void set_indirizzo(const char* i){delete [] indirizzo; indirizzo=new char[strlen(i)+1]; strcpy(indirizzo,i);}
            bool operator<(const PaccoPostale& );
            const PaccoPostale& operator=(const PaccoPostale& );
        private:
            int codice;
            float peso;
            char* indirizzo;
    };


        typedef PaccoPostale T;
    //  typedef int T;

    struct Rec{
        T elem;
        Rec* next;
    };

    class Pila{
        public:
            Pila(){start();}
            ~Pila(){if(l!=0) delete [] l;}
            void start(){l=0; n=0;}
            void push(const T& );
            void pop(T& );
            void top()const;
            bool empty()const{return (n==0);}
            bool full()const{return (n==N);}
        private:
            Rec* l;
            unsigned int n;
    };

//the method that generates the problem when T is PaccoPostale is the `//following`

void Pila::push(const T& e){
    if(l==0){
        l=new Rec;
        l->elem=e;
        l->next=0;
    }else{
        Rec* t=0;
        if(l->elem<e){
            t=new Rec;
            t->elem=e;
            t->next=l;
            l=t;
        }else{
            t=l->next;
            Rec* p;
            while(t!=0 && (t->elem)<e){
                p=t;
                t=t->next;
            }
            if(t==0){
                t=new Rec;
                p->next=t;
                t->elem=e;
                t->next=0;
            }else{
            //  if((t->elem)==e)
            //      throw Errore();
                Rec* q;
                q=new Rec;
                q->elem=e;
                q->next=t->next;
                t->next=q;
            }
        }
    }
}

const PaccoPostale& PaccoPostale::operator=(const PaccoPostale& p){
        codice=p.codice;
        peso=p.peso;
        set_indirizzo(p.indirizzo);
    }

 /*   The function should add to the linked list a new element in order but without generating segmentation fault at run time but as i said the return value when i use that method in the main is not 0 but 3221225477.*/


//this is the main that returns the value i'm talking about

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    PaccoPostale p(1,2,"ok");
    Pila pil;
    pil.push(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `push()` returns nothing. what return value are you talking about? also where is the segfault? not working and segfault are very different

Comment: The return value is in the main, where i use the method. Now i include that too in the code.

Comment: Where's the copy-assignment operator implementation for PaccoPostale?

Comment: I just added it, i don't know if it could be the cause for the problem but do not think so

Comment: you added the copy-constructor, I asked for the copy-assignment operator

Comment: Okok sorry, my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "`new`" something then you need to "`delete`" it. Calling "`delete[]`" on something you called "`new`" on (instead of `new[]`) is undefined behavior.

In your case you called `l=new Rec` in `Pila::push` but then later called `delete [] l;` in `Pila::~Pila`

The most minimal change would be something like

```
Pila::~Pila() {
    while(l!=0) {
        auto next = l->next;
        delete l;
        l = next;
    }
}
```

Or you can get `Rec` a proper set of copy and destruction operations, up to you.